# Ubuntu 12.04 update error:failed to fetch cd rom

Tags: apt

I have been trying to update ubuntu 12.04 but each time i am getting the following error..can anyone help me.

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
```

Comment: thnx  saiarcot895

Answer (score -1):

Download cdimage manually from 
www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

write it to a usb or dvd

boot from the usb or dvd

select install option

then select update. It will update your previous ubuntu to the newer one you downloaded.

Comment: Could you expand?